# Why is a literal quoted list not the same as a list built by list constructors

Tags: lisp, racket

```lisp
(equal? '(1 2) (cons 1 2)) ; #f
```

Why exactly are these two not equivalent considering lists are just that — [illusion built on top of cons cells](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html).

Comment: saying 'the "standard" way' is inaccurate, one is a constant value, ie. a literal quoted list built at read-time, while the other is a list built by list constructors

Comment: I think the introduction of that chapter makes it pretty clear that `(cons 1 2)` is *not* a list.

Comment: `(equal? '(1 . 2) (cons 1 2)) ; ==> #t` Notice the added dot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(cons 1 2)` does not create a proper list. It creates a cons cell with two elements, both are numbers.

A normal list is recursively defined as:

- the empty list
- or a *cons cell* with an object as the *car* and a **list** as the *cdr*.

In your call `2` is not a list, but a number. The second argument to `cons` must be a list to get a proper list.

`(1 2)`

- in `(1 2)`, the *car* element is a number, the *cdr* element is `(2)`.
- in `(2)`, the *car* element is a number, the *cdr* element is `()`, the empty list.
- `()` is the empty list.

Thus `(1 2)` is a list according to the definition above.
`(cons 1 2)` creates `(1 . 2)`, which is not a list according to the definition above, since `2` is not a list.

Answer (score 5):

A list is a chain of conses, with one cons for each element. So `'(1 2)` is equivalent to `(cons 1 (cons 2 '()))`, which can be simplified to `(list 1 2)`.

The literal equivalent to `(cons 1 2)` is `'(1 . 2)`

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged "racket" and "lisp", here I'm using the Common Lisp language but apart from details this is the same in Racket.

The literal list as read by the Lisp reader when reading the following text:

```
'(1 2)
```

can be built by evaluating the following form:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))
```

This is different from:

```
(cons 1 2)
```

Which also can be read using a special syntax, as follows:

```
'(1 . 2)
```

Comment: You'd use `'()` or `null` instead of `nil` in Racket.